# Year data report using t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have got simple project data

```
Project     Year    Sum
512-17      2011    3147625,79
512-43      2011    652935,22
512-43      2012    23982,68
512-52      2012    584541,35
512-52      2013    3353388,73
512-52      2014    3935164,39
```

How to init result data from 2010 to current year like that

```
Project     Year    Sum
512-17      2010    0 -- if not exist in current data init with year and zero Cost
512-17      2011    3147625,79
512-17      2012    0
512-17      2013    0
512-17      2014    0
512-17      2015    0
512-43      2010    0
512-43      2011    652935,22
512-43      2012    23982,68
512-43      2013    0
512-43      2014    0
512-43      2015    0
512-52      2010    0
512-52      2011    0
512-52      2012    584541,35
512-52      2013    3353388,73
512-52      2014    3935164,39
512-52      2015    0
```

Comment: have you tried anything, we would like to see how you are approaching the problem. so that we can suggest some constructive and corrective improvements on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
;WITH Years AS
(
    SELECT 2010+number [Year]
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
    AND 2010+number <= YEAR(GETDATE())
)
SELECT  P.Project,
        Y.[Year],
        ISNULL(T.[Sum],0) [Sum]
FROM Years Y
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Project
            FROM dbo.YourTable) P
LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable T
    ON Y.[Year] = T.[Year]
    AND P.Project = T.Project
```

You need to start with a list of every year that you want (I did this using a numbers table, but you should have a table with this information somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

Just posted a similar code on another thread:

```
DECLARE @StartYear INT = 2010
DECLARE @EndYear INT = 2014

;WITH MyCte ([Year])
AS
(
    SELECT  [Year] = @StartYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  [Year] + 1 FROM MyCte WHERE [Year] < @EndYear
)
,ProjectList ([Project], [Year], [Sum])
AS
(
    SELECT '512-17', 2011, '3147625,79' UNION
    SELECT '512-43', 2011, '652935,22' UNION
    SELECT '512-43', 2012, '23982,68' UNION
    SELECT '512-52', 2012, '584541,35' UNION
    SELECT '512-52', 2013, '3353388,73' UNION
    SELECT '512-52', 2014, '3935164,39'
)
SELECT  DISTINCT P.[Project], M.[Year], [Sum] = 0
FROM    ProjectList P
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [Year] FROM MyCTE WHERE [Year] NOT IN (SELECT [Year] FROM ProjectList WHERE [Project] = P.[Project])) M
```

Comment: This isn't giving the results wanted by the op

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  project
 ,y.year
 ,Sum
from (select 2010 as year
      union all
      select 2011
      union all
      select 2012
      union all
      select 2013
      union all
      select 2014
      union all
      select 2015) y
left join pd 
  on y.year = pd.year
order by Project
        ,y.year
```

Answer (score 0):

using `Recursive CTE`

```
 with
 CTE
 as
 (
 select N=1,0 as d
 union all
 select N+1,2009+N as d from CTE where N<7
 )select distinct Tab.Project,d ,ISNULL(Tab1.[Sum],0) from CTE 
 CROSS JOIN   (SELECT DISTINCT Project
            FROM dbo.MyTable)   Tab
    LEFT JOIN MyTable Tab1
 on CTE.d=Tab1.[Year] 
 and Tab.Project=Tab1.Project
 where d!=0
 ORDER BY Tab.Project,d
```